# Understanding this simplest example of a $\Sigma$ measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ be a measurable space.

The simplest example of a $\Sigma$ measurable function is the characteristic function of $A \in \Sigma$.

The characteristic function $\chi_A (x)= 1$ when $x \in A$ and $\chi_A (x)= 0$ when $x \notin A$

I know a function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is called measurable with respect to $\Sigma$ if

$$\{x \mid f(x) < c \} \in \Sigma \text{ for every } c \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Looking at the set $\{x \mid \chi_a (x) < c \}$.

Why is this set non empty when $ c \leq 0$?

Why does this set equal the complement of $A$ when $c \in (0,1]$?

Why does this set coincide with $X$ when $c \geq 1$?

What does "coincide with $X$" mean?

Comment: Do you know what is a characteristic function? All your questions are immediate once you know the definition.

Comment: In my opinion you have to define $\chi_a(x)$

Comment: "$*$ coincide with $X$" means "$*$ is $X$".

Comment: @silviaGhinassi yes. As I have stated in the question

Comment: Well, now that you have defined it, you should be able to answer your own questions.